# while using ng-repeat, how to set ng-checked true if a value exist in another angular array?

Tags: angularjs, multidimensional-array, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-checked

// array of already assigned districts

```
$scope.already_assigned = [{"zone":"1","district":"2"}];
```

// array of all districts

```
$scope.all_districts = [{"districtId":"1","districtName":"All Districts","stateId":"1"},{"districtId":"2","districtName":"District 09","stateId":"7"},{"districtId":"3","districtName":"District 10","stateId":"7"},]
```

//Html

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="list in all_districts">
<td>
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="checkAlreadyAssigned(list.districtId)" > </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

How to make a function similar to checkAlreadyAssigned(list.districtId). 
This function should take the district ID and check this district ID exists in the already_assigned array and return true if yes or return false.
Please.

Comment: what do u save in already_assigned?  how is the combination zone + district related to the districtId?

Comment: @ZivWeissman   already_assined is an array that return by a query from assignment table where districts are assigned to various zones(M to M). Query will fetch result where zoneID=x. tnks

Comment: K, then I guess @tymeJV got you covered ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.some` on the already assigned portion to check if the ID exists:

```
$scope.checkAlreadyAssigned = function(id) {
    return $scope.already_assigned.some(function(obj) {
        return obj.district === id
    });
});
```